# Can I program on iPad 2?

Tags: php, ipad, apache, xampp, mamp

I am a Web development and try to work with iPad 2. Please tell me know may I install: Apache, PHP, MySql on iPad ? or install XMAPP/MAMP Pro on iPad 2 ?

If not, which table can do that (not Windows OS) ?

Thanks so much !

Comment: You can't, not without jailbreaking your iPad.

Comment: Technically, you can write an app that is basically a local web server with php mysql support. Many photo or art app's basically create a local server so you can access your content from the app on local wifi without having to connect your device after force transfer to photo gallery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can use various text editing tools to write your code on an iPad. Then sync it with your test server.

2) There aren't any such magic packages like XAMPP for iPad that will let you easily install your usual PHP/MySQL Apache LAMP magic easily. Someone has yet to write an app that will let you run a PHP-parsing server on your iPad, although many app's provide local web server's for photo sharing and such usage on iDevice's.

3) You can also program and "compile on the cloud" on the iPad. The emphasis is on the cloud, but the plus is that you can execute and test your PHP script's right on your iPad (though you will need WiFi or 3G). You can write your own app and set up your own server for that, or you can use one of several existing iPad app's that also do that.

4) If you have remote access to your main coding machine with all that installed, you can also use your iPad to remote access the machine. Keep in mind that this will have the usual virtual terminal lag.

Some useful links:

http://www.koderapp.com/

http://www.macstories.net/ipad/padedit-ipad-optimized-ide-on-your-server/

http://blog.owensperformance.com/2010/03/mides-1-8-release/

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ieditor-all-in-one/id434810905?mt=8

---

Since I wrote the answer in 2011, there have been several IDEs that actually let you run code locally on iOS, such as:

Python for iOS http://pythonforios.com/‎

Kodiak for PHP and Javascript http://www.becomekodiak.com/

Draftcode PHP http://freeridecoding.com/draftcode/

Mides PHP http://www.owensperformance.com/mides/

Codea http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/

Answer (score 8):

There is an app for the iPad that allows writing and executing code on the Ipad: http://www.becomekodiak.com/

I am a co-author of this app, so I hope it is okay to mention my own product here. But it seems to be related to the topic.

Comment: Can this be used to build PHP-apps that run offline on an iPad (obviously without the end using being able to work with the code)?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, but if you take a look at http://www.becomekodiak.com/ you'll see what the app can do.

Comment: MySQL support is coming in the next release.

Answer (score 3):

There is now also another alternative App that features offline code execution called DraftCode. It includes PHP 5.4.10 and also supports POST/GET form parsing and all the things that usually are the webserver's responsibility.
It also lets you do document interchange with other applications (like DropBox).

I have written it because I wanted a more minimalistic alternative to what was available.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to do the same since the iPad was great for portability but did not find a whole lot available.  Other than what I list below

**Web Server:** The only possible local server that I've seen so far is http://www.lighttpd.net/ but requires jail breaking your iPad.

**Code Editor** Textastic http://www.textasticapp.com/ is great.  It has support for DropBox and FTP and even some basic page previewing.  However, it's no where close to a full blown IDE like Eclipse.  But it's definitely great for basic updates.

Answer (score 1):

To do web development, you don't need to install those tools on an iPad.
You can develop whatever you want on a seperate development environment (say linux) and access that using the web browser in iPad.

Answer (score 1):

You can code on the iPad, but I could not find any dev server directly built in an app (as far as I remember, that's because apps that can run code directly within the iPad are not allowed on the iPad). Most code editors provide an FTP or webdav client, but nothing autonomous.

I don't know android as well as iOS, but projects exist, like this one :

http://www.phpforandroid.net/

Maybe you should give a look.

Hope that helps !

Benjamin